# app is getting crashed-random number generator

Tags: android, random, numbers

This is my java file of Random number generator. Whenever I run the app it get crashed. Help me out!

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    int  k;

    public void lol(View v) {

        EditText e1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.e1);
        EditText e2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.e2);
        TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.t);
        int h = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(e1));
        int i = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(e2));
        Random u = new Random();

        k = h + u.nextInt(i);
        t.setText(k);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Post your stacktrace.

Comment: You need to be more specific. Please post the log.

Answer (score 2):

You need to get the text from EditText. Also you need to use try catch block while parsing string to Integer or else it may throw RuntimeException if String can't be parsed to int.

```
public void lol(View v) {

    EditText e1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.e1);
    EditText e2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.e2);
    TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.t);
    String e1Text = e1.getText().toString();
    String e2Text = e2.getText().toString();
    try{
        int h = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(e1));
        int i=Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(e2));
        Random u = new Random();


        k = h + u.nextInt(i);
        t.setText(k);
    }catch(Exception e){
        //some exception
    }
}
```

Comment: @nesbak203 Then thank sanjeet by checking this as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error probably your random number is less than 0 (zero) . It is better to generate random number in range  like this

```
Random rn = new Random();
int range = maximum - minimum + 1;
int randomNum =  rn.nextInt(range) + minimum;
```

Comment: A negative number would probably not be what the OP intended but it would still result in a valid string - I don't think that that would cause an exception.

Comment: @EJoshuaS OP didn't post stact trace yet , so I just guessed .

Comment: Fair enough - it is hard to tell for sure what's going wrong without logs.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try something like the following (note that this is Xamarin for Android so it's C#, not Java):

```
public void lol(View v)
    {
        EditText e1 = (EditText)FindViewById(Resource.Id.e1);
        EditText e2 = (EditText)FindViewById(Resource.Id.e2);
        TextView t = (TextView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.t);

        int h, i, k;

        // TryParse tries to parse the text as an integer and returns a value
        // indicating whether or not it succeeded
        // e1.Text is equivalent to a call to e1.getText()
        if (int.TryParse(e1.Text, out h) && int.TryParse(e2.Text, out i))
        {
            Random u = new Random();

            k = h + u.Next(i);
            // This is equivalent to doing a call to t.setText(...)
            t.Text = k.ToString();
        }
    }
```

So, basically, you check to make sure that it actually *is* an int before you try to use it. Also, this is a better way to get the value of the text from EditText.